# I installed Wordpress locally now how do I login?

Tags: php, admin, wp-admin, login, xampp

I downloaded a WordPress website that I am modifying for a friend. 
He gave me access to cPanel, where I downloaded the SQL and changed it on [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/).

Now when I open `>localhost/wp` it opens the website but without the control panel.

I think to modify I need to access `>localhost/wp/wp-admin` but I don't have the username or password.

Do I have to ask him for it? Am I in the wrong path to modify the website?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you know the `username` you can have WP automatically log you in. You might need to ask your *friend* what that is.

Check to see if you're [logged in](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) and if not, [get user by login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by), [set the current user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user) along with the [auth cookie](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie) then redirect to the [~~user's admin~~](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/user_admin_url/)  url or [edit user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_edit_user_link) url to change the password.

Place this in the `functions.php` of the currently activated theme.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'automatic_login' );

function automatic_login() {
    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | SET THE USERNAME TO LOGIN WITH
    |---------------------------------------------------------------- 
    */

    $username = "Admin";

    /*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | AUTOMATICALLY LOG IN | THEN CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD! 
    |---------------------------------------------------------------- 
    */

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_wp_error( $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username ) ) ) {

        // Clear any auth cookies
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();

        // Log the user in
        wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );

        // Admin Dashboard
        // $redirect_to = user_admin_url();

        // Go directly to the Edit User page to change your password
        $redirect_to = get_edit_user_link( $user->ID ) . '#password';
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say downloaded, do you mean exported (using the all in one migration plugin or similar).

If so then yes, you need the username and password.

I'm not sure if you're talking about ssh.

Comment: I exported using phpadmin. I also got to modify a password via php admin so i could get in.
The thing is, i have the website locally, and i know how to run it, but i dont know how to get in a page that allows me to modify, in localhost/wp/wp-admin it opens a page that doesnt allow me to modify the layout.
Hope you can help me with this, thank you!

Comment: ? Do you have a username and password that allows you to login via WordPress?  If so you're good, if not you need a crack and I'm no expert at hacking into WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the page content, you need to ask the the password to your friend and login via `localhost/wp/wp-admin`. You can also create generate your own password and replace it in the database.

If you want to modify the website structure, you have to open `{your_webstite_folder}/wp-content/themes/{theme_name}` and you'll find here every files you need to modify the website.

However I strongly recommend you to create a child theme and modify the child theme only. https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial